# .pgpass is working for one user but not the postgres user

Tags: postgresql

There are `.pgpass` entries to an `rds`/`postgres` database on my laptop:

```
15.207.x.y:1234:clip:clip:whatever1
15.207.x.y:1234:postgres:clip:whatever2
```

The first one for `clip` user is working. The second for `postgres` user is not.  I have run

```
psql -p 1234 -h $RDSI -U clip -d clip
```

and it works without password.  Instead

```
psql -p 1234 -h $RDSI -U postgres -d clip
```

requires/prompts for the password.  When I put the password (nominally `whatever2`) it does connect.

What is different between the two to cause the difference in behavior?  The `db owner` is `clip` but that should not affect this process .. ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have user and database swapped. Your 2nd line should be `15.207.x.y:1234:clip:postgres:whatever2` for user `postgres`. Per [the docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-pgpass.html), the format is `hostname:port:database:username:password`.